# How does delegatecall work from Solidity 0.5.0 onwards?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-debugging, abi, delegatecall

I am trying, for learning purposes only, to make a mutable smart contract, but I couldn't find anything useful on stackexchange because everything I found was using `pragma solidity ^0.4.x;`

So, I have 2 contracts

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract first {
    uint calculationResult;
    address public linkedContract;

    function calculate(uint firstNumber, uint secondNumber) public {
        calculationResult = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    }
}
```

and the other

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract second {
    uint calculationResult;
    address public linkedContract;

    function changeContract(address newContract) public {
        linkedContract = newContract;
    }

    function delegatedCalculation(uint firstNumber, uint secondNumber) public {

    }
}
```

I am trying to make on the second contract the function `delegatedCalculation` to use the function from the first contract, so later I can change this to another calculation, I can for example create a third contract where the calculation is a sum, not a multiplication, I have tried 2 ways to do that, the way every tutorial and guide and even stackexchange answer I found does this is

```
linkedContract.delegatecall(bytes4(keccak256("calculate(uint, uint)")), firstNumber, secondNumber);
```

but when I try to compile on remix I get a not very helpful error

> browser/firstContract.sol:20:9: TypeError: Wrong argument count for function call: 3 arguments given but expected 1. This function requires a single bytes argument. If all your arguments are value types, you can use abi.encode(...) to properly generate it.`

And upon reading about that `abi.encode` I have found that if I do

```
linkedContract.call(abi.encode("calculate(uint, uint)", firstNumber, secondNumber));
```

it compiles, but then if I execute it nothing happens. I have created a function

```
function getReturnedView() public view returns(uint){
    return returnedValue;
}
```

I compile and run on Remix EVM the first, get it's address, compile the second, run it, execute the `changeContract` to give it the address of the first one, call the `delegatedCalculation`, and when I call the `getReturnedView()` it says just `0: uint256: 0`

I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `delegatecall` arguments are incorrect, you should use:

```
function delegatedCalculation(uint firstNumber, uint secondNumber) public {
        bool status;
        bytes memory result;
        (status, result) = linkedContract.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256("calculate(uint256,uint256)")), firstNumber, secondNumber));
    }
```

Or simply you can write the following if there is no return value, as this is the case for your `calculate`, method:

```
function delegatedCalculation(uint firstNumber, uint secondNumber) public {
        (bool status,) = c2.delegatecall(abi.encodePacked(bytes4(keccak256("calculate(uint256,uint256)")), firstNumber, secondNumber));
}
```

Note that:

1. To calculate the selector you should use `uint256` not `uint`.
2. Use `abi.encodePacked` to pack all the parameters into a bytes type.
3. `delegatecall` will return a bool indicating success or failure and a bytes with the 
   returned value (if any)

Test it in remix and it works. Hope this helps you.

EDIT: The clarification made in the docs is in the [breaking changes section](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.2/050-breaking-changes.html#semantic-and-syntactic-changes), this is probably what you were looking for.

> - The functions `.call()`, `.delegatecall()`, `staticcall()`, `keccak256()`, `sha256()` and `ripemd160()` now accept only a single bytes argument. Moreover, the argument is not padded. This was changed to make more explicit and clear how the arguments are concatenated. Change every `.call()` (and family) to a `.call("")` and every `.call(signature, a, b, c)` to use `.call(abi.encodeWithSignature(signature, a, b, c))` (the last one only works for value types). Change every `keccak256(a, b, c)` to `keccak256(abi.encodePacked(a, b, c))`. Even though it is not a breaking change, it is suggested that developers change `x.call(bytes4(keccak256("f(uint256)"), a, b)` to `x.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("f(uint256)", a, b))`.
>
>   - Functions `.call()`, `.delegatecall()` and `.staticcall()` now return `(bool, bytes memory)` to provide access to the return data. Change `bool success = otherContract.call("f")` to `(bool success, bytes memory data) = otherContract.call("f")`.

---

You can check sample for `call` and `delegatecall` with solidity 0.5 here: https://gist.github.com/Muhammad-Altabba/55ac6974ac9396d723fdfd792d51eb5d

Comment: OMG it works, can you link me something from the documentation or somewhere else I can read about it? I am a beginner and I am struggling to find content to find how exactly a few things work because apparently there is too much lower lever stuff, more than other programming languages I am used to. Thank you very very much

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Both examples should be using `abi.encodeWithSelector()`, not `abi.encodePacked()`. The reason you must use `abi.encodeWithSelector()` is  because you including the function selector (`bytes4(keccak256("calculate(uint256,uint256)"))`) along with the parameters. `abi.encodePacked()` encodes _parameters_ only, not the selector.